# Handler on onViewCreated kills Fragment animation

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, fragment, handler

I have a simple Fragment with this in the onViewCreated method:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        if (account != null) {
            try {

                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.postDelayed(() ->
                {
                    String decryptedCode;
                    try {
                        decryptedCode = (vaultService).getDecryptedPassword(account).trim();
                        in_password.setText(decryptedCode);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Helper.showMessage(e.toString());
                    } finally {
                        in_password_layout.setHelperText("");
                    }
                }, 1);


       
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Helper.showMessage(e.toString());
            }
        }


    }
```

and calling the Fagment i have:

```
    protected void openFragment(BaseFragment fragment) {

        fragment.setCaller(this);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.activity_slide_in_right, R.anim.activity_slide_out_left, R.anim.activity_slide_out_right, R.anim.activity_slide_in_left);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

The problem that i am facing is that if i remove the Handler call from the onViewCreated method, the transition occurs perfectly. If i put the Handler, like so, it kills the animation and just shows the fragment without any animation.
If i use the handler.postInFrontOfQueue the animation works, but takes a while before coming in. Which means it processes the Handler first and only then executes the animation and transits to the Fragment.
Do you have any idea how can i prevent this? I already tried in an independent Thread and it does not work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution. I have to put the amount of time it takes for the animation to occur in the 2nd parameter of the postDelayed method.

In my case:

```
getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime)
```

So it only triggers the handler after the animation finishes.

Not exactly what i wanted but it works. I would rather have it both process in parallel so that when the animation finishes the Handler is also done with its work.